# Somatória em SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou precisando fazer um relatório com `SQL`, que me pede a seguinte situação.

No relatório geral, eu preciso que fique assim:

```
Produto       Quantidade Total     Valor total

Salpicão      30kgs                810,00
```

O detalhe é, preciso que seja os relatórios que contem o item “Quantidade total” demandam a quantidade total do produto levando em conta todos os pedidos realizados.

```
SELECT   produto.nome, produto.tipo_medicao, 
 (select count(produto.valor) FROM produto) as total  
   FROM produto LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Comecei a fazer assim mas não está certo, segue o diagrama de banco:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você está procurando se chama `GROUP BY`! Agrupe os produtos pelo nome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisar é fazer um curzamento de dados com a tabela `itens_pedido` usando `JOIN` no caso usei o `INNER JOIN` para pegar apenas os produtos que possuem pedidos.
Mas ai você pode pesquisar melhor e ver o que atende sua necessidade, nessa `query` também estou retornando a somatória do produto no seu valo original e o valor que ele possui na tabela de `itens_pedido`

```
SELECT
    p.nome,
    SUM(IFNULL(ip.quantidade,0)) AS quantidade_total,
    SUM(IFNULL(ip.valor_total,0)) AS valor_total_pedido,
    SUM(p.valor) AS valor_produto
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN itens_pedido ip
ON ip.produto_id_produto = p.id_produto
GROUP BY p.id_produto;
```