# Dificuldades em fazer select

Tags: mysql, sql

Queria uma ajuda em como resolver os 3 últimos selects a baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que os relatórios que contem o item “Quantidade total” demandam a quantidade total do produto levando em conta todos os pedidos realizados.

```
SELECT pedido.horario_pedido AS horario,
    pedido.nome_cliente AS nome,
    nome_pedido.lista_pedido AS pedido,
    query_total_preco.valor_total,
    contato???
FROM
        pedido
    JOIN
        itens_pedido itens
    ON
        pedido.id_pedido
        =
        itens.pedido_id_pedido
    JOIN
(
SELECT
    pedido.id_pedido AS id_pedido,
    string_agg(produto.nome,', ') AS lista_pedido
FROM
    itens_pedido pedido
    JOIN
    produto
    ON
    pedido.produto_id_produto = produto.id_produto
GROUP BY
    pedido.id_pedido
) AS nome_pedido

ON
    pedido.id_pedido = nome_pedido.id_pedido


JOIN

(SELECT pedido_id_pedido AS id_pedido,
    SUM(valor_total) AS valor_total
FROM
    itens_pedido
GROUP BY (pedido_id_pedido) ) AS query_total_preco

ON

nome_pedido.id_pedido = query_total_preco.id_pedido
```

Até comecei tentar fazer o segundo mas não saia

Se puderem me ajudar ficarei agradecido

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://jsfiddle.net/dc2rxmgn/

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Somatória em SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263982/somat%c3%b3ria-em-sql)

Comment: @arllondias Não me parece duplicata.

Comment: coloca no sqlFiddle... nao tem a estrutura das tabelas...

Comment: só um min que coloco

Comment: a estrutura do banco e o fiddle

Comment: rsrs, o fiddle, tem que ser no SQLFiddle... mas tá...

Comment: como que ele funciona?

Comment: de um lado, coloca o código de criação das tabelas e inserts, build no esquema, e do outro lado, realiza as queries

Comment: cara, rola de abrir um chat entre nos?

Comment: @GabrielFalieri Precisa ter no mínimo 15 pontos para participar de chats neste site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou tentar fazer a query sem valida-la, estou sem o mysql aqui e sem o fiddle também... faça um teste

O segundo resultado, acredito que ficaria assim (Não identifiquei a coluna que seria o 'Contato'):

2-

```
Select
    p.horario_pedido,
    p.nome_cliente,
    GROUP_CONCAT(concat(ip.quantidade,pp.tipo_medicao,' - ',pp.nome)) as descricao,
    sum(ip.valor_total) as total
from pedido p
inner join itens_pedido ip on ip.pedido_id_pedido = p.id_pedido
inner join produto pp on pp.id_produto = ip.produto_id_produto
group by p.horario_pedido, p.nome_cliente
```

3-

```
Select
    s.nome_setor,
    pp.nome,
    sum(ip.quantidade) as quantidade_total,
    pp.tipo_medicao
from pedido p 
inner join setor s on s.id_setor = p.setor_id_setor
inner join itens_pedido ip on ip.pedido_id_pedido = p.id_pedido
inner join produto pp on pp.id_produto = ip.produto_id_produto
group by s.nome_setor, pp.nome,pp.tipo_medicao
```

4-

```
select
    p.horario_pedido,
    p.nome_cliente,
    GROUP_CONCAT(concat(ip.quantidade,' ',pp.nome)) as pedido,
    s.nome_setor
from pedido p
inner join itens_pedido ip on ip.pedido_id_pedido = p.id_pedido
inner join produto pp on pp.id_produto = ip.produto_id_pedido
inner join setor s on s.id_setor = p.setor_id_setor
group by p.horario_pedido, p.nome_cliente, s.nome_setor
```

Comment: ficou perfeito mano

Comment: a medida que for fazendo os outros selects, coloco aqui. Se outro usuário responder com mais informações, sinta-se a vontade pra desmarcar a resposta =]

Comment: os outros 2 não rola de dar uma moral não?

Comment: alterei aí...tem gente me esperando pra sair, quando voltar termino, vlw

Comment: cara, até o 3 perfeito, rola de fazer o 4 tb?

Comment: o 4 nao deu certo ?

Comment: só falta ele pra eu terminar os reports

Comment: ah não vi que tinha posto

Comment: deu certo sim, obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o seu `JOIN itens_pedido itens ON pedido.id_pedido = itens.pedido_id_pedido` não deveria estar lá.

É importante manter nomes diferentes para as diferentes tabelas consultadas para evitar confusão, ainda mais quando uma mesma tabela é consultada mais de uma vez de formas diferentes.

Assim sendo, cheguei a essa SQL aqui abaixo, embora eu acredite que deve dar para simplificar mais.

```
SELECT
    a.horario_pedido AS horario,
    a.nome_cliente AS nome,
    c.lista_pedido AS pedido,
    d.valor_total
FROM pedido a
-- INNER JOIN itens_pedido b ON a.id_pedido = b.pedido_id_pedido
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        e.pedido_id_pedido AS id_pedido,
        GROUP_CONCAT(f.nome SEPARATOR ', ') AS lista_pedido
    FROM itens_pedido e
    INNER JOIN produto f ON e.produto_id_produto = f.id_produto
    GROUP BY e.pedido_id_pedido
) AS c ON a.id_pedido = c.id_pedido
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        g.pedido_id_pedido AS id_pedido,
        SUM(g.valor_total) AS valor_total
    FROM itens_pedido g
    GROUP BY g.pedido_id_pedido
) AS d ON c.id_pedido = d.id_pedido
```

Comment: STRING_AGG não existe.. é mysql D;

Comment: @GabrielFalieri Então tente com `GROUP_CONCAT`. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Alguém ajuda no report 4?